# How to write unit test for test task with dynamic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stub, shim

I have no idea of how to write unit test for BroadcastChangeNotification(). Any advice? I mean how to use stub or shim to test this static function. it's hard for me to fake related context. maybe my question should be "how to check the ConfigurationChanged() was been called?"

```
public class ConfigurationHub : Hub
{

    private static readonly IHubConnectionContext 
        ConnectionContext = GlobalHost
            .ConnectionManager
            .GetHubContext<ConfigurationHub>()
            .Clients;


    public static void BroadcastChangeNotification()
    {
        Task.Run(() => ConfigurationHub
            .ConnectionContext
            .All.ConfigurationChanged());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idear of how to write unit test for BroadcastChangeNotification(). Any advice?

Comment: The question should be in the question, not in the comment. Also, you didn't provide enough information to receive an useful answer.

Comment: Am i not clear? just don't know how to use stub or shim to test the function BroadcastChangeNotification().

Comment: In your shoes, I would be thinking more about testing the outcome of `ConfigurationChanged()` rather then whether it has been called, since `BroadcastChangeNotification()` isn't doing anything really.

Comment: The problem is you're using static methods - this makes `BroadcastChangeNotification` untestable in unit-testing sense. You can only test it with more general, *integration* testing approach, and only verify its final outcome. To make it testable introduce an appropriate interface instead of `ConfigurationChange` so you can mock it.